# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with github example using node.js and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing my first script with Selenium WebDriver using code from github and it's giving me the following error:

> node index.js                                                                                                                                                           (node:1165) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server terminated early with status 127                                                                                                                                                     at earlyTermination.catch.e (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:252:52)                                                                                                                   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)                                                                                                                                                                            From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()                                                                                                                                                                                                            at Function.createSession (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)                                                                                                                    at Function.createSession (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)                                                                                                                           at createDriver (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)                                                                                                                                      at Builder.build (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:642:16)                                                                                                                                     at example (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/index.js:11:57)                                                                                                                                                                          at Object. (/mnt/d/Development/selenium_test/index.js:18:3)                                                                                                                                                                at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)                                                                                                                                                                                   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)                                                                                                                                                                     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)                                                                                                                                                                                       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)                                                                                                                                                                                 (node:1165) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   (node:1165) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I'm enclosing the package.json file and the index.js file:

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "selenium_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Selenium First Test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Jesús García Potes",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.41.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.12.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
  }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
require('chromedriver')
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

(async function example() {
  let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  try {
    await driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
    await driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver', Key.RETURN);
    await driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);
  } finally {
    await driver.quit();
  }
})();
```